# Calling a Javascript Function from Console

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

In Chrome's JavaScript console, how do I call a function that belongs to a .js file included in the webpage I am viewing?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If it's inside a closure, i'm pretty sure you can't.

Otherwise you just do `functionName();` and hit return.

Comment: not for me: `functionName();` is ok in firebug shows 'undefined' in chrome developer tools.

Comment: `undefined` is the return value of the function. Chrome's dev tools automatically print the return of any function invoked from the console. If it wasn't working, you'd see `ReferenceError: functionName is not defined` in red.

Comment: Nobody could become confused by this behaviour, right? :)

Comment: @KevinEnnis I thought you were wrong, and then I saw that my css was hiding my change that my js was making. Good catch.

Answer (score 30):

An example of where the console will return ReferenceError is putting a function inside a JQuery document ready function

```js
//this will fail
$(document).ready(function () {
    myFunction(alert('doing something!'));
    //other stuff
})
```

To succeed move the function outside the document ready function

```js
//this will work
myFunction(alert('doing something!'));
$(document).ready(function () {          
    //other stuff
})
```

Then in the console window, type the function name with the '()' to execute the function

```
myFunction()
```

Also of use is being able to print out the function body to remind yourself what the function does. Do this by leaving off the '()' from the function name

```
function myFunction(alert('doing something!'))
```

Of course if you need the function to be registered after the document is loaded then you couldn't do this. But you might be able to work around that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony. Perfect answer

Answer (score 6):

This is an older thread, but I just searched and found it. I am new to using Web Developer Tools: primarily Firefox Developer Tools (Firefox v.51), but also Chrome DevTools (Chrome v.56)].

I wasn't able to run functions from the Developer Tools console, but I then found this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad

and I was able to add code to the Scratchpad, highlight and run a function, outputted to console per the attched screenshot.

I also added the Chrome "Scratch JS" extension: it looks like it provides the same functionality as the Scratchpad in Firefox Developer Tools (screenshot below).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scratch-js/alploljligeomonipppgaahpkenfnfkn

Image 1 (Firefox):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkS7W.jpg

[image]

Image 2 (Chrome): https://i.stack.imgur.com/cndGC.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke it using

```
window.function_name()
```

or directly without `window` like

```
function_name()
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, there are two cases here:

1. Your function is in global scope. In that case, simply open a console and call it `yourFunction()`
2. Your function is scoped inside some other function(s) and is not accessed globally. In that case, you can open a Sources tab, locate your .js file, place a breakpoint anywhere at the bottom of the outer function (you might need to refresh a page after that if the code have already been run) and call `yourFunction()` in console. Also, while at breakpoint you may do something like `window.yourFuncRef = yourFunction` in console, to be able to access it later at any time.

Comment: I tried the 2nd option above, and it almost works, I added a line and placed a breakpoint, and when trying to call my function in the form of var = function, I got an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: showBuy is not defined", but the console itself showed me the function, I just had to tab+enter

Comment: If you get undefined, this could mean you have placed a breakpoint before the actual definition of a function. maybe you can give more details about how the function is defined and where you set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered this issue.  I was able to get around it by using indirection.  In each module define a function, lets call it `indirect`:

```
function indirect(js) { return eval(js); }
```

With that function in each module, you can then execute any code in the context of it.

E.g. if you had this import in your module:

```
import { imported_fn } from "./import.js";
```

You could then get the results of calling `imported_fn` from the console by doing this:

```
indirect("imported_fn()");
```

Using `eval` was my first thought, but it doesn't work.  My hypothesis is that calling `eval` from the console remains in the context of console, and we need to execute in the context of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be that you're importing the ".js" file as a module.

```
<script type="module" src="example.js"></script>
```

I had the same problem and deleting 'type="module"' attribute worked for me.

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
```