# select a answer in dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have some issues with this html code, and i need to select a specific shoesize :

```
<select name="shoeSize" id="shoeSize" autocomplete="off" class="ncss-ncss-select-menu fs-block css-1bxej0k erx5h8s0" aria-required="false" aria-describedby="shoeSize-select-aria-description">


    <option hidden="" data-testid="hidden-option" disabled="" value="" aria-hidden="true">Pointure</option>
<option value="4">EU 36</option>
<option value="4.5">EU 36.5</option>
<option value="5">EU 37</option>
<option value="5.5">EU 38</option>
<option value="6">EU 38.5</option>
<option value="6.5">EU 39</option>
<option value="7">EU 40</option>
<option value="7.5">EU 40.5</option>
<option value="8">EU 41</option>
<option value="8.5">EU 42</option>
<option value="9">EU 42.5</option>
<option value="9.5">EU 43</option>
<option value="10">EU 44</option>
<option value="10.5">EU 44.5</option>
<option value="11">EU 45</option><option value="11.5">EU 45.5</option><option value="12">EU 46</option>
<option value="12.5">EU 47</option>
<option value="13">EU 47.5</option>
<option value="13.5">EU 48</option>
<option value="14">EU 48.5</option>
<option value="14.5">EU 49</option>
<option value="15">EU 49.5</option>
<option value="16">EU 50.5</option>
<option value="17">EU 51.5</option><option value="18">EU 52.5</option></select>
```

i have tried answers i found on the website but it does not work like :

```
document.getElementById("shoeSize").selectedIndex =5;
document.getElementById(".shoeSize").value=5;
document.getElementById("shoeSize").value = 5;
```

the dropdown does not show any values changed

Comment: The `selectedIndex` property does not function as you seem to think it does. You need to set this value to an *index*, not the target `<option>`’s `value`. I would encourage you to read [the documentation for this attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: i don't get why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

your JavaScript will be

```
 function selectOptionByIndex() {
            document.getElementById('shoeSize').getElementsByTagName('option')[11].selected = 'selected'
        }
```

you can use your own index in place of 11.

Or if you want to set option by value then use below code

```
function setSelectedValue() {
            var selectObj = document.getElementById('shoeSize');
            var valueToSet = "8.5"
            for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
                if (selectObj.options[i].value == valueToSet) {
                    selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i don't get it if i enter the command document.getElementById('shoeSize').getElementsByTagName('option')[11].selected = 'selected' in the chrome console nothing happens, the same value is still selected whatever number i choose

Comment: I have verified both methods for selecting option. On which event are you calling these methods ?

Comment: for instance if i put in the console :  var selectObj = document.getElementById('shoeSize');
var valueToSet = "8.5"
for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObj.options[i].value == valueToSet) {
        selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}. it returns always undefined

Comment: putting in console will not work. You need to call the methods on some event like onload or on button click. If you have specific requirement to do only on console then modify your question.

Comment: oh sorry im new i did not know, how would it be in the console please? thank you

Comment: For console please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054870/calling-a-javascript-function-from-console/42320912

Comment: are you sure it works, this affects nothing the webpage i just tried