# Can I call a function in iframe, if it's inside a closure?

Tags: javascript, iframe, closures, microsoft-edge

I have this crazy idea of:

- Embedding [fast.com](https://fast.com/) in an iframe on my own website
- Triggering it by `restartTest()` or `click` on `div#speed-progress-indicator-icon`

[image]

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251453/1469208) that I can trigger any method, event or function in embed iframe:

```
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();
```

But then [it seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9054881/1469208) I can't trigger it, because it is inside a closure.

On "master" side (no embed) it goes like this:

```
var o = document.getElementById('speed-progress-indicator-icon');
o.click();
```

Will it work in the iframe as well?

I am asking (instead of trying myself), because I can't do any tests myself from where I am writing right now, sorry -- can't modify or save any files. Can only run console commands on read-only accessed files.

And the thing that makes me suspicious that I am doing this all wrong (and thus that it certainly won't work in an iframe) is that am I getting this error after `o.click()`?

```
app-a32983.js:3 
    
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'className')
at hasClass (app-a32983.js:3:24556)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app-a32983.js:3:27092)
at <anonymous>:1:3
```

Can anyone advice on what am I missing here?

(Edge 110, Windows 11 Pro)

Comment: The much bigger problem with embedding fast.com on *your* page is that you'll have to access content in a cross-origin iframe, which is likely not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it work in the iframe as well?

No, it won't work if you put it in an iframe (also tested here). Script access to a frame's content is subject to the same-origin policy. In this case, it is obvious that it does not conform to the same-origin policy.

For more information of iframe (same-origin policy), you can read [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#scripting).